# Difference between transpose() and .T in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample of data:

```
d = {'name': ['Alice', 'Bob'], 'score': [9.5, 8], 'kids': [1, 2]}
```

I want to display simple statistics of the dataset in pandas using `describe()` method.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df.describe().transpose())
```

*Output 1:*

[image: result_1]

Is there any difference between the two workflows when I am ending up with the same result?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df.describe().T)
```

*Output 2:*

[image: result_1]

---

**References:**

- [Pandas | API documentation | pandas.DataFrame.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

Comment: the property T is an accessor to the method transpose().

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [T](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas.DataFrame.T) ?  _Reflect the DataFrame over its main diagonal by writing rows as columns and vice-versa. **The property T is an accessor to the method transpose().**_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference. As mentioned in the [`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) attribute documentation, `T` is simply an accessor for the [`transpose()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) method. Indeed a quick look in the [pandas DataFrame source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.24.x/pandas/core/frame.py#L2700) shows that the entire implementation of `T` is nothing more than:

```
T = property(transpose)
```