# Pandas dataframe convert row to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am fetching data from a source into a pandas data frame, it is like below

| date | currency | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d1 | INR | 31 |
| d2 | INR | 32 |
| d2 | USD | 21 |
| d3 | USD | 41 |
| d3 | INR | 51 |
| d3 | JPY | 61 |

I want to convert it to below

| date | INR | JPY | USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d1 | 31 | 0 | 0 |
| d2 | 32 | 0 | 21 |
| d3 | 51 | 61 | 42 |

Comment: Hi Elric. Please provide us example code producing the sample data. And you can look into pandas `pivot()` function. Don't only tell us what you want but what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to rotate your data around the `currency` column, then use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to replace `NaN` values with `0`, and then finally [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to clean up the output:

```py
df.pivot(index='date', columns='currency', values='price') \
.fillna(0) \
.reset_index() \
.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  date  INR   JPY   USD
0  d1   31.0   0.0   0.0
1  d2   32.0   0.0  21.0
2  d3   51.0  61.0  41.0
```

Comment: Hi @Nick, thanks for your answer. I made a mistake in my questions initially, it is 'date' col and not 'data' I corrected it later. Now when I use your solution, I get below error. raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape")
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @Elric Since this question has been closed, I suggest you ask a new one, including some data which demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to reshape the DataFrame, then transpose it with [`T`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54735337/4713169).

```
df.pivot(index="currency", columns="data", values="price").T
```

Output:

```
currency    INR   JPY   USD
data            
d1          31.0  NaN   NaN
d2          32.0  NaN   21.0
d3          51.0  61.0  41.0
```

Comment: Please improve your answer. Explain it. Explain the steps. What happens before `T` and how such sub results look like.